# Incompatible generic wildcard captures

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, capture

in the following snippet:

```
package test;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class WildcardsTest<K, V> {
    private Iterator<Map.Entry<K, ? extends Collection<V>>> iterator;
    public WildcardsTest(Map<K, ? extends Collection<V>> map) {
        iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
        /* Type mismatch: cannot convert from
           Iterator<Map.Entry<K,capture#1-of ? extends Collection<V>>> to
           Iterator<Map.Entry<K,? extends Collection<V>>> */
    }
}
```

The assignment is incorrect, although the types seem to match exactly.

I've devised a dirty workaround by specifying the type of the Collection as another generic parameter, like this:

```
public class WildcardsTest<K, V, C extends Collection<V>> {
    private Iterator<Map.Entry<K, C>> iterator;
    public WildcardsTest(Map<K, C> map) {
        iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
    }
}
```

But that `C` parameter is really a "don't care" type that only complicates the API, is there any way to get rid of it while maintaining type safety?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this and it will work:

```
private final Iterator<? extends
    Map.Entry<K, ? extends Collection<V>>
> iterator;
```

You can still use the iterator like this:

```
public void foo(){
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Entry<K, ? extends Collection<V>> entry = iterator.next();
        Collection<V> value = entry.getValue();
    }
}
```

For reference, read [the get and put principle](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp07018.html#3.0) (originally from [Java Generics and Collections](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527754))

Comment: wonderful! once more, the solution is another level of indirection xD

Answer (score 2):

> **The assignment is incorrect, although the types seem to match exactly.**

The two `?`-wildcards can be bound to two different classes. Put it this way, it is quite obvious that there is a type mismatch:

```
private Iterator<Map.Entry<K, ArrayList<V>>> iterator;
public WildcardsTest(Map<K, HashSet<V>> map) {
    iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
}
```

When you introduce the `C`, you "force them" to refer to the same class.