# Incompatible wildcard types that should be compatible

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, unbounded-wildcard

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459587/incompatible-generic-wildcard-captures), which provides a solution but doesn't explain it (unfortunately, the links in the answers are now dead):

Take the following method:

```
void method(Map<?, ?> myMap) {
    Set<Map.Entry<?, ?>> set = myMap.entrySet();
    ...
}
```

Simple, no? However, this fails to compile on jdk1.7.0_25:

> ```
> incompatible types
> required: java.util.Set<java.util.Map.Entry<?,?>>
> found:    java.util.Set<java.util.Map.Entry<capture#1 of ?,capture#2 of ?>>
> ```

WTF? `Map.entrySet()` is specified as returning an object of type `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>>`, so in the example above, `myMap.entrySet()` returns a `Set<Map.Entry<?, ?>>`. But it doesn't compile!

Even weirder, from the linked question at the top, changing the method to this makes it compile:

```
void method(Map<?, ?> myMap) {
    Set<? extends Map.Entry<?, ?>> set = myMap.entrySet();
    ...
}
```

***WTF???*** Calling `entrySet` on a `Map<?, ?>` returns a `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>>`, which can't be assigned to a variable of type `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>>`, but it can to a variable of type `Set<? extends Map.Entry<K, V>>`?????

Can anyone shed light on what's going on here? And does this mean that, whenever I write a method using a wildcard type at least 2 levels deep, I have to remember to make it `? extends ...` somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, dup :( It's hard to find similar questions when the problem is so specific :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each of those ? can vary independently, so there's no guarantee that the `<?,?>` in the declaration of `myMap` matches the `<?,?>` in the declaration of `set`.

What this means is that once I have a `Set<Map<?,?>>`, I can put *any* type of `Map` into that set, because `Map<?,?>` is a supertype of all types of `Map`.  But this is not a property that `Set<Map<String,Integer>>` (for example) has - it's far more restrictive in terms of what types of map I can put into it.  So `Set<Map<?,?>>` is not a supertype of `Set<Map<String,Integer>>`.  But `myMap.entrySet()` could easily be a `Set<Map<String,Integer>>`, depending on what `myMap` is.  So the compiler has to forbid us from assigning it to a variable of type `Set<Map<?,?>>`, and that's what's happening.

On the other hand, `Set<? extends Map<?,?>>` *is* a supertype of `Set<Map<String,Integer>>`, because `Map<String,Integer>` is a subtype of `Map<?,?>`.  So it's OK to assign `myMap.entrySet()` to a variable of type `Set<? extends Map<?,?>>`.

Note that there's nothing special about `String` and `Integer` here, but `myMap` has to be a map of *something!*

You could write

```
<K, V> void method(Map<K, V> myMap) {
    Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> set = myMap.entrySet();
    ...
```

Comment: I don't understand. It's a wildcard, so it doesn't matter what it is - the compiler can make the `?`s in `set` the same as the `?` returned from `entrySet`, _because they're both wildcards_.

Comment: Your answer isn't wrong, but I don't think that it's obvious why each of the wildcards varying separately means that the wildcarded `myMap`'s entry set method returns `Set<?>` and not `Set<Map.Entry<?,?>>`.

Comment: Also, my actual problem is more complicated than this - the return value of `entrySet` is being passed to a method parameter of type `Collection<Map.Entry<?, ?>>`. Fortunately, I can change the method being called...

Comment: No, the compiler can't make the `?`s into whatever it likes.  `Map<?,?>` is a supertype of every type of Map, and `Map.Entry<?,?>` is a supertype of every type of Map.Entry.  So you could easily make them incompatible types.  This is how the compiler stops you from doing that.

Comment: @David Isn't that what his fix does anyway?

Comment: @MattBall - You're right, it wasn't obvious.  I hope the new paragraph that I've just added clarifies it a bit.

Comment: @Deadron - I guess so, but I thought that OP was really after an explanation more than anything else.  After all, he/she did find a fix, even though it was different from my fix.