# How to write a method which accepts any collection of classes which extend Throwable?

Tags: java, generics

I want to pass a collection of classes which extend `Throwable` to a method. However, my attempt fails to compile in Netbeans with jdk1.6.0_39:

```
package com.memex.sessionmanager;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

public class GenericsDemo
{
    public void foo(Collection<Class<? extends Throwable>> c)
    {
    }

    public void bar()
    {
        foo(Collections.singleton(RuntimeException.class));
    }
}
```

The compiler says `foo(java.util.Collection<java.lang.Class<? extends java.lang.Throwable>>) in com.memex.sessionmanager.GenericsDemo cannot be applied to (java.util.Set<java.lang.Class<java.lang.RuntimeException>>)`.

I can make it compile by changing the calling code to:

```
foo(Collections.<Class<? extends Throwable>>singleton(RuntimeException.class));
```

but I'd rather not force clients to write this obtuse generic type. Is it possible to write a method which will take any collection of classes which subtype `Throwable`?

**EDIT:**

[Someone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21409883/839128) fixed the above example with the method signature:

```
public <T extends Throwable> void foo(Collection<Class<T>> c) {}
```

But I'm now having problems *using* the parameter. Specifically, I want to assign it to a field, like this:

```
package com.memex.sessionmanager;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

public class GenericsDemo
{

    private Collection<Class<? extends Throwable>> throwables;

    public <T extends Throwable> void foo(Collection<Class<T>> c)
    {
        throwables = c;
    }

    public void bar()
    {
        foo(Collections.singleton(RuntimeException.class));
    }
}
```

But the compiler says:

```
incompatible types
found   : java.util.Collection<java.lang.Class<T>>
required: java.util.Set<java.lang.Class<? extends java.lang.Throwable>>
```

Comment: Related: [incompatible types and fresh type-variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543966/incompatible-types-and-fresh-type-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work on Java 7:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Generics {
  public void foo(Collection<? extends Class<? extends Throwable>> c) { 
  }

  {
    foo(Collections.singleton(RuntimeException.class));
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it works for me on Java 6 as well, just took me a while to write correctly. Thanks :)

Comment: ok, but how to pass actual collection with more than one element there?

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
public <T extends Throwable> void foo(Collection<Class<T>> c) {}
```

Comment: Sorry for so many edits; I kept messing up the formatting. I wish people would wait before downvoting. :L

Comment: This was very prompt and fixed my example, thank you. But I'm now having trouble using the parameter. I've edited the question.

Comment: @MikeFHay So you want to pass it the set returned from Collections.singleton?

Comment: Sorry the example is contrived. I want to pass it any collection of `Throwable` Classes (including the `Set<Class<RuntimeException>>` returned by `Collections.singleton` in my example). I then want to assign that Collection to a field.