# create a list of generic classes

Tags: java, generics, java-7

I have a utility method that creates a one-element list out of some object:

```
public static final <T> List<T> list(T t) {
    final List<T> rv = new ArrayList<>();
    rv.add(t);
    return rv;
}
```

I also have a method that accepts an argument of type `List<Class<?>>`. So I have to create an object of that type. Here's what I try to do:

```
final Class<?> aClass = Integer.class;
final List<Class<?>> trivialListOfClasses = list(aClass);
```

… this fails with:

```
[javac] /some/path/Foo.java:41: error: incompatible types
[javac]             final List<Class<?>> trivialListOfClasses = list(aClass);
[javac]                                                                  ^
[javac]   required: List<Class<?>>
[javac]   found:    List<Class<CAP#1>>
[javac]   where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
[javac]     CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
[javac] 1 error
```

What's the proper way to accomplish the above? I understand the part about Java generics being invariant but what exactly is going on here?

Comment: Why did you write your own version of `Collections.singletonList()`?

Comment: The solution it seems, is to update your Java version, this works fine in `1.8.0_144` for me.

Comment: I tried `Collections.singletonList(aClass)` and also `Arrays.asList` before that. They still give the same error. I wanted to understand what's going on.

Comment: @JornVernee Alas, I don't get to dictate that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543966/incompatible-types-and-fresh-type-variable might help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was able to reproduce with `-source 7 -target 7` on `javac 1.8.0_144`.

One thing that works if you're only planning to take things out of the list is to use `? extends Class<?>`:

```
Class<?> aClass = Integer.class;
List<? extends Class<?>> trivialListOfClasses = list(aClass);
Class<?> bClass = trivialListOfClasses.get(0); // works
// trivialListOfClasses.add(String.class); // doesn't work, though
```

What also works is to manually supply the generic type in the call to `list`:

```
Class<?> aClass = Integer.class;
List<Class<?>> trivialListOfClasses = Util.<Class<?>>list(aClass);
Class<?> bClass = trivialListOfClasses.get(0); // works
trivialListOfClasses.add(String.class); // also works
```

It seems that the compiler just isn't able to reconcile the wildcard type of `List<Class<?>>` with the one returned by `list` on it's own.

Comment: 1+, usually simple supplying *more* type information solves these kind of riddles

Answer (score 1):

```
final List<Class<?>> trivialListOfClasses = list(aClass);
```

works in Java 1.8 and 9

```
final List<?> trivialList = list(aClass);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
final List<Class<?>> trivialListOfClasses = (List<Class<?>>) trivialList;
```

is a workaround for 1.7. Seems like the 1.7 compiler cannot verify the type returned from `list(T t)` is dependent on `T`

Answer (score -2):

There is a [oracle javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html) i'am not so sure about either but it works in java 8. And 9 is just out ;)

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    final Class<?> aClass = Integer.class;
    final List<Class<?>> trivialListOfClasses = Program.list(aClass);

}

public static final <T> List<T> list(T t) {
    final List<T> rv = new ArrayList<>();
    rv.add(t);
    return rv;
}
```