# Wildcard Type Mismatch (int) compilation error, but not (String)

Tags: java, wildcard

I've read several questions that are similar to mine, but I still don't undestand what's happening, or why it only happens for the (int) and not for the other more complex types:

```
    HashMap<?, ?> returncp = startAndWaitForJob("DSP_WF_" + operation, cp);

    DSPResponseDTO dto = (DSPResponseDTO) returncp.get("RESPONSE_OBJECT");
    String respDesc = (String) returncp.get("statusInfoResponseDescription");
    int respCode = (int) returncp.get("statusInfoResponseCode");
```

The compilation error:

```
[javac]         int respCode = (int) returncp.get("statusInfoResponseCode");
[javac]                                             ^
[javac]   required: int
[javac]   found:    CAP#1
[javac]   where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
[javac]     CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

The questions already perused:

[incompatible types and fresh type-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543966/incompatible-types-and-fresh-type-variable)

[Bounded-wildcard related compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907262/bounded-wildcard-related-compiler-error)

[Java: Wildcard Types Mismatch Results in Compilation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736325/java-wildcard-types-mismatch-results-in-compilation-error)

Comment: can you give jsfiddle or any other link for your program code?

Comment: You're trying to assign an `int` to a `String`?

Comment: @Kayaman sigh.. sorry it was late and I copy errored here. It's int respCode = (int) returncp.get("statusInfoResponseCode"); and the error is exactly the same

Comment: I think `HashMap<?, ?>` does not work as you expect. What happends when you write `HashMap<Object, Object>` or just `HashMap` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First what is `CAP#1`

I found this [quote](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp04298/):

> What on earth does "capture#337 of ?" mean? When the compiler encounters a variable with a wildcard in its type, such as the box parameter of rebox(), it knows that there must have been some T for which box is a Box. It does not know what type T represents, but it can create a placeholder for that type to refer to the type that T must be. That placeholder is called the capture of that particular wildcard. In this case, the compiler has assigned the name "capture#337 of ?" to the wildcard in the type of box. Each occurrence of a wildcard in each variable declaration gets a different capture, so in the generic declaration foo(Pair x, Pair y), the compiler would assign a different name to the capture of each of the four wildcards because there is no relationship between any of the unknown type parameters.

Now let's go back to the message `CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?`

It considers the `CAP#1` as an instance of `Object`, more like an instance of a class extending the class `Object`.

Now one need to imagine that the generic are transform into cast at compile time. Which means that:

```
HashMap<?, ?> map = new HashMap();
int test = (int) map.get("");
```

is more or less the equivalent of:

```
HashMap<?, ?> map = new HashMap();
int test = (int) (Object) map.get("");
```

Which is not possible (or allowed by the compiler) to cast an `Object` into an 'int'.
Of course, this `Object` is used to make it simple to represent.

But it is totally possible to cast an `Object` into a 'String' or an 'Integer'.

So what you could do is:

```
HashMap<?, Integer> returncp = startAndWaitForJob("DSP_WF_" + operation, cp);
```

In that case you will not even need to cast anything ([see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)).

But if that is not possible for any reason:

```
int respCode = ((Integer) returncp.get("statusInfoResponseCode")).intValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what types are in your map, but here

```
String respCode = (int) returncp.get("statusInfoResponseCode");
```

you cast the result of the `get`call to an `int`and assign it to a `String`.

If it is an `Integer`, use

```
Integer respCode = (Integer) returncp.get("statusInfoResponseCode");
```

Comment: sigh.. sorry it was late and I copy errored here. It's int respCode = (int) returncp.get("statusInfoResponseCode"); and the error is exactly the same. If you'd delete this answer it would be appreaciated

Comment: @WurmD Did you at least try casting to `Integer`?